# How to improve Spring batch performance while working on more than 8 million records

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to generate reports in my project using spring batch. I have more than 10 million records in my database. Complete process is taking more than 44 hours to generate the report.

Earlier I have set commit-interval as 1 but after reading some articles, I have set commit-interval as 10000 and page-size as 10000. I am using Task executor as well. But still, it's taking more than 44 hours to generate the report. In every iteration, It is taking 3 to 4 minutes to get the records, processes those records and writing in my CSV file.

```
Jobs-Context.xml 

<job id="reportJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"> 

<!-- master step, 10 threads (grid-size) --> 
<step id="masterStep"> 
<partition step="slave" partitioner="rangePartitioner"> 
<handler grid-size="10" task-executor="taskExecutor" /> 
</partition> 
<next on="*" to="combineStep"/> 
</step> 

<step id="combineStep"> 
<tasklet> 
<chunk reader="multiResourceReader" writer="combineFlatFileItemWriter" 
commit-interval="1" /> 
</tasklet> 
<next on="*" to="deleteFiles"/> 
</step> 

<step id="deleteFiles"> 
<tasklet ref="debitfileDeletingTasklet" /> 
</step> 
</job> 

<!-- each thread will run this job, with different stepExecutionContext 
values. --> 
<step id="slave" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"> 
 <tasklet> 
<chunk reader="pagingItemReader" writer="flatFileItemWriter" 
processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="10000" /> 
</tasklet> 
</step> 

<bean id="rangePartitioner" class="com.test.RangePartitioner" /> 

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor"> 
   <property name="corePoolSize" value="10" /> 
   <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" /> 
   <property name="allowCoreThreadTimeOut" value="true" /> 
 </bean> 


itemreader bean 


<bean id="pagingItemReader" 
class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader" 
scope="step"> 
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
<property name="queryProvider"> 
<bean 
class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean"> 
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
<property name="selectClause" value="SELECT * " /> 
<property name="fromClause" value="***QUERY****/> 
<property name="whereClause" value="where rn between :fromId and :toId" /> 
<property name="sortKey" value="rn" /> 
</bean> 
</property> 
<!-- Inject via the ExecutionContext in rangePartitioner --> 
<property name="parameterValues"> 
<map> 
<entry key="fromId" value="#{stepExecutionContext[fromId]}" /> 
<entry key="toId" value="#{stepExecutionContext[toId]}" /> 
</map> 
</property> 
<property name="pageSize" value="10000" /> 
<property name="rowMapper"> 
<bean class="com.hello.ItemRowMapper" /> 
</property> 
</bean>
```

The whole process of read/write takes more than 44 hrs which is not acceptable to the client. How do i scale using spring batch.i want the job to complete this within overnight. Is it possible to generate a report having more than 8 million records using Spring Batch.

Comment: is it possible to split up the work to be run on different nodes? then aggregated later?

Comment: Maybe use BigData: Hadoop, Spark etc?